# Is it possible to import JNDI context.xml file from file system into Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

We have a huge enterprise application which has a lot of JNDI entries written inside context.xml file. Currently the context.xml file is kept inside META-INF folder of our application. We need to move it out of the application and the server so that we can modify the JNDI entries whenever needed. We cannot keep it anywhere inside tomcat root folder, as we are using an image file to start the server and we wont be able to access the files inside server.

So I would like to know if it is possible to import the JNDI context file from the file system using spring ? If not spring, do we have any other alternatives to get this done ? I have been researching for 2 days and haven't found a solution yet.

**EDIT:**
Yes, I accept all these answers and that's the way we have been doing it all these years. Either keep the context.xml in the meta-inf folder inside the application or keep it in server conf directory or place it under conf/catalina/localhost/warfilename.xml. All these approaches work. But now we are doing a research on whether it is possible to have the xml file outside of the server in our local file system and have either tomcat or our application to import it. Please let me know if this is possible. It's a kind of research we are doing.

The reason being, we will sell our products to a lot of customers and we have our product bundled as an image file. For every customer we cannot create an image file separately. So we are just trying to move the context.xml file outside of our image and keep it configurable outside our application or server, so that we can modify the jndi entries when we install our product in customer's machine.

Please let me know if the question is still not clear. I really thank you for your help.

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: The *whole idea* of the context.xml file is that it *already is* outside the application proper., in the file system rather than in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do.

JNDI is a naming and directory lookup service for the server side.  Clients should *not* be modifying those settings.

The `context.xml` has to be in the Tomcat `/conf` folder.  No question about that.

I'm assuming "client" means a user interface that's talking to the server side.

If "client" means "other applications that are running on a single Tomcat instance, then that is even more true.  Why should one client be able to modify a value that others use?

Spring has JNDI object factories.  Those are how Spring would use JNDI.

Maybe the reason you can't find anything telling you how to do it is that no one should be doing such a thing.

It's still not clear what requirements you are imagining.  Please clarify and I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the Tomcat `conf` folder. It can be provided in the webapp's META-INF directory.

Comment: I've never set up Tomcat that way.  It's an app server concern, not an application.  JNDI resources can be shared by any app that's deployed.  What if they have the same name with conflicting values?  What happens then?

Comment: Yes, I accept all these answers and that's the way we have been doing it all these years. Either keep the context.xml in the meta-inf folder or keep it in server conf directory or place it under conf/catalina/localhost/warfilename.xml. But now we are doing a research on whether it is possible to have the xml file outside of the server inside a local file system and have either tomcat or our application to import it. Please let me know if this is possible. It's a kind of research we are doing.

Comment: In our case no other application will be deployed in our server. So there is no way two applications are going to share this jndi context.

Comment: All the more reason to put the JNDI context.xml on the server and configure Spring to use it.  You have not convinced me that any import is needed.

Comment: Hi duffymo, as I mentioned in my edit, we will bundle our server and our application inside an image file and install it in our customers machines. But we may have to modify the jndi entries for each customer. Since we have it as an image, we cannot modify the jndi context inside the server. So for each customer we have to modify the jndi context and create a new image file. So we are just trying to externalize our context.xml so that we can have it outside our image file (which means outside our server and our product) configurable for each customer.

Comment: I'm aware that it is not a standard practice to move the context file outside of our server. But I just want to know if this is possible or not. If there are any approaches please let me know.